# Updating a unique value in child table oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have parent table customer id is primary key 
In customer details table - customer id is reference key

I need to update negative values to customer id in child table.

In parent I have 1 customer id - 1000
In child table I have 10 records for customer 1000 - I need to update same nagative value  for 10 records in customer child table. Like this I need to update whole table

I need to achieve with SQL query not with PLSQL

Ex: I tried with few case it's not working

```
Update customer details A set A.customer id = -1000+1
Where customer id in (
  select B.customer id 
  from customer master 
  where B.customer id = A.customer id 
)
```

It updating different values to child table for single customer

Is it possible to update every customer in child table with unquie value based on customer with single update query

Master table

```
Customer id   name 
1000          Kim
1001          June
```

Child table

```
Customer id.  
1000
1001
1000
1001
```

I need to update 1000 and 1001 with unique I'd is this possible in single query

Comment: `from customer master` <-- a typo?

Comment: `set A.customer id = -1000+1` will always set to -999.

Comment: Customer typo is - number

Comment: @PrabhakarSubramani . . . "I need to update negative values to customer id in child table."  I see no negative values in your sample data.